# why is not considered the third and fourth paragraph within the first parent div , When we use the counter?

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.child:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}

.red {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent ">
  <!-- paragraph  1 -->
  <p class="child">item</p>
  <!-- paragraph  2 -->
  <p class="child">item
    <div class="parent  red">
      <p class="child">item</p>
      <p class="child">item</p>
      <p class="child">item
        <p>
          <p class="child">item</p>
        </p>
      </p>
    </div>
  </p>
  <!-- paragraph  3 -->
  <p class="child">item</p>
  <!-- paragraph  4 -->
  <p class="child">item</p>
</div>
```

**Note**: If we use this counter with the `<ol>` element,
And the increase and addition of each `<li>` element inside, the process will be done naturally without mixing .

Comment: Because, I suspect. **`p` elements can't contain `div` or other `p` elements** and the browser is closing the `p` for you. This is *invalid* HTML

Comment: If I change all your "div"s to "ol", and all your "p" to "li" , and add  list-style-type: none; on the ol it works.